# Match an array value with another multidimensional array and then get the values from the multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, laravel, loops, multidimensional-array, matching

I want to Match Array 1 values with the value of  array 2 `key DATE` and if it found matched value then print value of `MIN_TIME`

Array 1:

```
array:13 [
  0 => 2020-02-13
  1 => 2020-02-12
  2 => 2020-02-11
  3 => 2020-02-10
  4 => 2020-02-09
  5 => 2020-02-08
  6 => 2020-02-07
  7 => 2020-02-06
  8 => 2020-02-05
  9 => 2020-02-04
  10 => 2020-02-03
  11 => 2020-02-02
  12 => 2020-02-01
]
```

Array 2:

```
array:8 [▼
  0 => {#1192 ▼
    +"USERID": "59"
    +"DATE": "2020-02-13"
    +"MAX_TIME": "17:11:14.0000000"
    +"MIN_TIME": "10:01:55.0000000"
  }
  1 => {#1194 ▼
    +"USERID": "59"
    +"DATE": "2020-02-12"
    +"MAX_TIME": "18:12:20.0000000"
    +"MIN_TIME": "14:08:25.0000000"
  }
  2 => {#1195 ▼
    +"USERID": "59"
    +"DATE": "2020-02-11"
    +"MAX_TIME": "18:22:09.0000000"
    +"MIN_TIME": "15:40:56.0000000"
  }
  3 => {#1196 ▼
    +"USERID": "59"
    +"DATE": "2020-02-10"
    +"MAX_TIME": "16:47:15.0000000"
    +"MIN_TIME": "14:07:19.0000000"
  }
  4 => {#1197 ▼
    +"USERID": "59"
    +"DATE": "2020-02-07"
    +"MAX_TIME": "16:29:40.0000000"
    +"MIN_TIME": "08:39:38.0000000"
  }
  5 => {#1198 ▶}
  6 => {#1199 ▶}
  7 => {#1200 ▶}
]
```

My Expected output is:

```
Date    Date From DB    Time
2/13/2020   2/13/2020   10:01:55 AM
2/12/2020   2/12/2020   2:08:25 PM
2/11/2020   2/11/2020   3:40:56 PM
2/10/2020   2/10/2020   2:07:19 PM
2/9/2020        Not Found
2/8/2020        Not Found
2/7/2020    2/7/2020    8:39:38 AM
```

I searched from google and tried all solution but failed, Can you guys please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Laravel Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections) to achieve this:

```php
$result = collect($array1)
    ->mapWithKeys(function ($item) {
        return [$item => null];
    })
    ->merge(
        collect($array2)->pluck('MIN_TIME', 'DATE')
    )
    ->toArray();

/* Output:
[
    2020-02-13 => 10:01:55.0000000
    2020-02-12 => 14:08:25.0000000
    2020-02-11 => 15:40:56.0000000
    2020-02-10 => 14:07:19.0000000
    2020-02-09 => null
    2020-02-08 => null
    2020-02-07 => 08:39:38.0000000
]
*/
```

You can use `map` or `transform` to get your expected result:

```php
$result = collect($array1)
    ->mapWithKeys(function ($item) {
        return [$item => null];
    })
    ->merge(
        collect($array2)->pluck('MIN_TIME', 'DATE')
    )
    ->map(function ($item, $key) {
        return [
            'Date' => $key,
            'Time' => $item
        ];
    })
    ->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

In below code we made for loop of first array element which you show in question.
And then match with your collection with first where. 
And print your table
Documentation :

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-first-where

```
$array=[
      0 => 2020-02-13
      1 => 2020-02-12
      2 => 2020-02-11
      3 => 2020-02-10
      4 => 2020-02-09
      5 => 2020-02-08
      6 => 2020-02-07
      7 => 2020-02-06
      8 => 2020-02-05
      9 => 2020-02-04
      10 => 2020-02-03
      11 => 2020-02-02
      12 => 2020-02-01
    ];
    //$dbcollection is the laravel collection which you getting from the db.
    // as per your second array printed we assume it will be same.
    // assign that array in $dbcollection variable.
    echo "<table>";
    foreach($array as $value){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>{$value}</td>";
        if ($dbrow=$dbcollection->firstWhere('DATE',$value)) {
            echo "<td>{$dbrow->DATE}</td><td>{$dbrow->MIN_TIME}</td>";
        } else {
            echo "<td colspan='2'>Not Found</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

Hope this will be work for you.